# How to track weights and gradients in a Keras custom training loop

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have defined the following custom model and training loop in Keras:

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

And I am using the following code to train the model on a simple toy data set:

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
hidden = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh')(inputs)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(hidden)

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/100)
y = np.sin(x)

nnmodel = CustomModel(inputs, outputs)
nnmodel.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1), loss="mse", metrics=["mae"])
nnmodel.fit(x, y, batch_size=100, epochs=2000)
```

I want to be able to see the values of the `gradient` and the `trainable_vars` variables in the `train_step` function for each training loop, and I am not sure how to do this.

I have tried to set a break point inside the `train_step` function in my python IDE and expecting it to stop at the break point for each epoch of the training after I call `model.fit()` but this didn't happen. I also tried to have them print out the values in the log after each epoch but I am not sure how to achieve this.